# Python: Program keeps looping but goes nowhere. How can I fix it?

Tags: python, loops, tree

I hate to ask a question like this, because I feel like I should really figure out the solution on my own, but I really am at a loss for what exactly is wrong with this code. I hope that a fresh set of eyes on it will reveal some flaw in something that I've taken for granted as functioning.

The goal of this program is to perform a graph search in order to solve a classic riddle. It starts with a parent node of all four bools set to false, and the goal is to get them all set to true. This is done by finding all valid children for the node (based on a validation function) and putting them into a 'tree' list of nodes. The parent is also put into an 'explored' list of nodes.

When looking for the next child to use, a loop looks in the tree list and finds the value with the lowest cost, while ignoring any nodes that are already in the explored list. Upon finding the next node with the lowest cost, it returns it as the new parent, and the loop begins once more. Once the goal node is reached, the loop exits, the path to the goal node is constructed, and printed in a special formatting.

That's all that's supposed to happen, but when I run the program, it simply goes on infinitely. Based on some debugging, I believe that there's a problem with my loop to find a new parent node. The first parent works fine, it is valid parent and gets the first batch of child nodes created and added to the tree list. Once the second is picked (which based on my calculations and confirmed by printing tests is an 'invalid' node), the progress goes as follows:

1. no new children are found (this is intended functionality for an invalid parent node)
2. the parent is not added to the tree list because it is already there (again, intended functionality)
3. the parent is added to the explored list because it was not yet found there (intended functionality, all good so far)
4. the loop for choosing the next parent appears, here's where things go wrong

As far as I can tell, the loop to select a new parent just continually selects that same second parent over and over again. I have debugged with printing tests to find that the entire while loop just goes forever picking and rejecting that exact same node, even when it shouldn't pick it more than once (since it was added to explored list).

Is there something wrong with my list that I'm not seeing? Here's the code for reference. Thanks to anyone who can help me out!

```
#for parent is not equal to goal
while not isGoal(parent):
    if validate(parent, explored):  
        getchildren(parent)
        #print parent.farmer

    #add parent to explored nodes
    if parent not in explored:
        explored.append(parent)
    if parent not in tree:
        tree.append(parent)
        #print parent.farmer

    #find next node to explore

    temp = node()
    temp.cost = sys.maxint  #this ensures that the first temp is always replaced by the first unexplored tree node
    for i in range(0, len(tree)):
            if tree[i] not in explored and tree[i].cost <= temp.cost:
                tree[i].copy(temp)
                #print temp.farmer, temp.wolf, temp.sheep, temp.cabbage
    temp.copy(parent)

#now return to the top of the while and do it again
```

EDIT: Here's the class definition as was requested:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.farmer, self.wolf, self.sheep, self.cabbage = False, False, False, False
        self.parent = None
        self.cost = 0
    def copy(self, child):
        child.farmer = self.farmer
        child.wolf = self.wolf
        child.sheep = self.sheep
        child.cabbage = self.cabbage
        child.parent = self
        child.cost = self.cost
```

There is no **eq** function.

EDIT: I added this eq function:

```
def __eq__(self, node):
        if self.farmer == node.farmer and self.wolf == node.wolf and self.sheep == node.sheep and self.cabbage == node.cabbage:
            return True
        return False
```

and changed this code in the node:

```
for i in range(0, len(tree)):
        for j in range(0, len(explored)):
            if tree[i].__eq__(explored[j]) is False and tree[i].cost <= temp.cost:
                tree[i].copy(temp)
                #print temp.farmer, temp.wolf, temp.sheep, temp.cabbage
    temp.copy(parent)
```

But it didn't change anything for me, the problem is still there.

Comment: This is a lot of code for an SO question.  Is there anyway you could trim it down?

Comment: I thought it might be a bit much. Sorry about that. I went ahead and trimmed it down to what I suspect is the most likely cause of my issue.

Comment: I looked at the complete code.  Something that was not obvious to me was how you are determining if two nodes are equal.  Your class "node" did not have an __eq__(self, other) method. This could be important because you create new nodes by cloning.  I'm assuming that when one checks if an object exists in a list, python is checking for equality.

Comment: As @aspiring.algorist said, if you don't have an explicit `__eq__` method in your Node class, then you might be having problems because they way python determines a node to be equal the way you want it to determine if nodes are equal. Can you show this part of the code again?

Comment: Sorry to disappear. I cannot access that code on this computer. I will try to access it elsewhere.Why exactly does Python require a specific method for such behavior? Not to bash it or anything, I'm just curious as a new user of the language.